# How to make POST method in WCF Rest service working when data is passed in it?

Tags: jquery, wcf, post

I have a wcf rest Service when i used GET method it works fine(they was passed along with the url). But i need to use post method and when there is no data to pass in post method it works fine. But when some data is added then it returns Bad Request error in IE and In mozila and chrome it just returns Error in the ajax jquery request.I have re-post this question here since i was not able to attach image..in the previous post. Please help...........

I have post the code i used in wcf service and ajax method below.pls help....

Code in Ischeduler.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface Ischeduler
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetData", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetDataName", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetDataName(string Name);
}
```

scheduler.cs

```
public string GetData()
    {
        string getdata = "hello";
        return string.Format("You entered" + getdata);
    }
public string GetDataName(string Name)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered" + Name);
    }
```

Ajax request in Schedular.aspx on button click

```
$("#btnInvoke").click(function () {
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "http://localhost:3125/schedulerAPI_Service/scheduler.svc/GetDataName",
                      data: '{"Name": "John"}',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      crossdomain: true,
                      success: function (data) {
                         alert(data);
                      },
                      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                          alert("failed " + error);
                      }
                  });
```

Wcf Web Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="InstaScribeCentralConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ATLT53;Initial Catalog=InstaScribeCentral;User ID=sa;Password=bmjobmjo;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="scheduler">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Ischeduler"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to enable [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your WCF Service.

I have noted few things in your configuration:

1. The service element has the name attribute value which should have been a fully qualified name.
2. The endpoint element has the contract attribute value which should have been a fully qualified name.

Ex:

```
SampleWCF.Scheduler (i.e. namespace.ServiceName)
```

Please see my sample to post data to a WCF Service in json format:

My WCF Service Method:

```
[WebInvoke]
public string GetParam(string Name)
{
    return Name + " from server";
}
```

Now posting some data from Fiddler:

[image]

The format you are using to post the data is not correct when you want to pass string.

Comment: Please see my updated answer on how to post the data when you have a string param in your REST WCF Service method

Comment: yeah thanks with the answer the issue was with the data i passed in the request

Answer (score 1):

have you done like below i.e added attribute to the servrice class

```
   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode 
        = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service : IService
    {
        // Your code comes here
    }
```

Check this article which is help you to achieve your task : [Calling WCF Services using jQuery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery)

**EDIT**

Check this post also may help you to complete your task : [Create REST service with WCF and Consume using jQuery](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2011/03/rest.html)

Comment: @deepu - than if possible follow the artile , download code and check fo your mistake

Comment: I'm using a rest service, the service will be a http://localhost:3125/schedulerAPI_Service/scheduler.svc/GetDataName link

Comment: The issue was with the data string passed in ajax request,  
data: '{"Name": "John"}' returns error then i made a object and JSON.stringify(obj) and passed post method worked.... I'm really confused with this error, since i have never come across such an error till now.. thanks Pranay Rana for your valuable answers

Answer (score 0):

Add exception handling on your service to see exactly what the exception is. This way you will not only solve this exception but you can gracefully handle other exceptions down the line in the future.

In your Global.asax file under Application_Start if you have not already created a config line add:

```
//where config is your WebApiConfiguration/HttpConfiguration file

config.ErrorHandlers = (Handlers, endpoints, descriptions) =>
            {
                Handlers.Add(new CustomErrorHandler(descriptions));
            };
```

And then create the exception handler added above class:

```
public class CustomErrorHandler : HttpErrorHandler
{
    public IEnumerable<HttpOperationDescription> Descriptions { get; set; }

    public CustomErrorHandler(IEnumerable<HttpOperationDescription> descriptions)
    {
        Descriptions = descriptions;
    }

    protected override bool OnTryProvideResponse(Exception exception, ref System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage message)
    {
        //use exception variable to see what the exception is and then you can either decide
        //to output a response to the user and do nothing further at which point you return true and set the message variable,        or you can just leave it false to return as is.

        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, what version are you using as the WCF Rest is now called WCF Web api and as far as I know it's on 0.6 which you can get through NuGet?